# Summing until time-condition is reached in Python

Tags: python, sum, conditional-statements

I want to sum over a certain, but rolling, period within my dynamic model. The formal representation is as follows

[image: The picture shows the discounted sum from <code>t</code> to <code>t+(mi-a)</code>]

A simple code snippet to run the equation is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import operator 

year = np.arange(50)
m_ = [50, 30, 15]
a = [25, 15, 7.5]
ARC_ = [38, 255, 837]
r = 0.03
```

I tried subtracting list `a` from `m_` by `list(map(operator.sub, m_, a)))` as found within another post.

My failed attempt looks something like this:

```
for t in year:
    for i in range(0, 3):
        while t < t+(list(map(operator.sub, m_, a))):
            L_[t] = sum(ARC_[i] / (1+r) ** t)
```

Comment: Is the goal to subtract element-wise a to m, i.e to get a list `[25, 15, 7.5]` and then to iterate `for each t: (while t < t + 25 then while t < t+15 then while t < t + 7.5)` And for each while doing the sum calculation and storing it somewhere (how?) ? And by the way, isn't the while loop infinite?

Comment: A couple of things is unclear: The boundary for while adds a single value and a list? Within while sum is called, but there is only a single expression to sum?

Comment: Could it be that your formula should be `L_i = ...`? Or maybe you want to also sum over `i` (as you do in your implementation)?

Comment: it is indeed the case that L is i specific. Sorry for that. The individual sums get aggregated based on probabilities later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all sure that I understood it right, I tried to base my answer on the equation. Even if it is still a bit of from the result you expect, it might help you to solve your issue.

I create a result list to store each value of L[t], i.e. 50 values. Then I compute the start / stop of the sum for every couple (t,i) and compute it.

```
import numpy as np

years = np.arange(50)
m_ = [50, 30, 15]
a = [25, 15, 7.5]
ARC_ = [38, 255, 837]
r = 0.03

result = []

for t in years:
    s = 0

    for i in range(3):
        t0 = t
        tf = t + m_[i]-a[i]
        for k in range(int(t0), int(tf+1)):
            s += ARC_[i] / (1+r) ** t

    result.append(s)
```

If what you wanted to do is to compute the difference element-wise between m and a, a simple solution is:

```
[m_[i] - a[i] for i in range(len(m_))]
```

Hope it helps.